# How to transform a python dictionary to a desired format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

I have the following dictionary, which i got when applied `to_dict()` method on a pandas dataframe.

```
{
   'name' : {
      0: 'abc',
      1: 'xyz'
    },
   'email': {
     0: 'abc@abc.com',
     1: 'xyz@xyz.com',
   },
   'category': {
     0: 'category 1',
     1: 'category 2', 
   }
}
```

How do I transform it into the following structure?

```
[
  {
    'name': 'abc',
    'email' : 'abc@abc.com',
    'category': 'category 1',  
  },
  {
    'name': 'xyz',
    'email' : 'xyz@xyz.com',
    'category': 'category 2',  
  }
]
```

I tried applying many variations of `for` loop, but came out as bogus code, if anyone could help or point to some links it would be great, python newbie here :|

**EDIT:** changed the desired structure to a list of dicts, as dicts are not hashble,

Comment: This seem like a really good exercise to learn more about python! I'd recommend trying to split the data into a way that you can then rebuild it into the desired format.  So perhaps make a list of all the name values, another of the email values, and a 3rd of the category values.  Once you have it organized, take the name, email, and category lists and turn them into dictionary key:value pairs.

Perhaps that will help you complete the task.  I'm just going off the top of my head how I'd initially try to solve this.  Good luck!

Comment: even i was thinking to do the same... thanks @J0hn

Comment: As a note for the future, you should usually include examples of your attempts, even if they failed. Most of the time it helps others produce  good answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The target structure you display is a set of dicts. Since dicts are not hashable, it is not possible to create.

Instead you probably want a list of dicts.

```
result = [
     {k: yourdict[k][n] for k in yourdict} for n in sorted(yourdict['name'])
]
```

Testing:

```
[
    {'category': 'category 1', 'email': 'abc@abc.com', 'name': 'abc'},
    {'category': 'category 2', 'email': 'xyz@xyz.com', 'name': 'xyz'}
]
```

Comment: Wonderful, It worked like a charm, if you could add a bit about how this works, it will be great for others like me as well

Comment: This is just python list comprehension (and dict comprehension which works the same for dicts.) see the python official basic tutorial, chapter 5.1.3 here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions and chapter 5.5 here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries @ShobiPP

Answer (score 4):

You could transpose your dataframe before converting it to a dictionary. This will produce a dictionary of dictionaries, where each key is an index value from the original dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({
   'name' : {
      0: 'abc',
      1: 'xyz'
     },
   'email': {
     0: 'abc@abc.com',
     1: 'xyz@xyz.com',
   },
   'category': {
     0: 'category 1',
     1: 'category 2', 
   }
}).T.to_dict()
```

Outputs:

```
{0: {'name': 'abc', 'email': 'abc@abc.com', 'category': 'category 1'},
 1: {'name': 'xyz', 'email': 'xyz@xyz.com', 'category': 'category 2'}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just pass `'records'` as the desired orientation to [`to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
df.to_dict('records')
```

The default orientation `'dict'` produces output like `{column -> {index -> value}}` as can be seen in your example, where as `'records'` a list like `[{column -> value}, … , {column -> value}]`, which is your desired output.